# Question about proof related to integration by Spivak

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-explanation

[image: proof]

[image]

Why was he allowed to use two partitions on the line "This means that for each...", didn't the original theorem only say "there is a partition P..." implying that they need to be the same or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove the converse, you are starting with the hypothesis that the supremum of lower sums equals the infimum of upper sums. The intermediate step is to show there exist partitions $P''$ and $P'$ (possibly different) for which the corresponding upper and lower sums differ by at most $\epsilon.$  The final step introduces $P$, a common refinement of $P'$ and $P''$.

Let $I = \sup_P  L(f,P) = \inf_P U(f,P)$.

By definition of the supremum (least upper bound) and infimum (greatest lower bound), there exist partitions $P'$ and $P''$ such that

$$\tag{*}U(f,P'') < I + \epsilon/2,$$ $$\tag{**}L(f,P') > I - \epsilon/2.$$

To clarify (*), since $I$ is the greatest lower bound for upper sums, then $I + \epsilon/2$ is not a lower bound, with a similar argument for (**).

Now subtract (**) from (*).

Comment: In the first proof: "Suppose first that for every..."
They go from P to both P', could one of them have been P' and the other being P'' instead?

Comment: That is the hypothesis for the forward implication, where you start with that and show that infimum of upper sums must equal supremum of lowers sums. The reverse implication starts with equality of the infimum and supremum as the hypothesis, and asserts that for some partition the upper and lower sum difference is less than $\epsilon$.  The two partitions are $P'$ and $P''$ are only used for that reverse proof.

Comment: I see you added to the comment.  The $P'$ is not a specific partition, just the dummy argument over which the sup and inf are taken. The notation is not the best.  I would use $\sup_{P'} L(f,P')$.  I

Comment: In the second proof $P'$ and $P''$ are meant to be specific partitions and $P$ is used as the argument for the sup and inf.